# How do I use Facebook php-sdk correctly

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Currently I use [Facebook php-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/).

Example code from the tutorial.

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
$me      = null;

if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}
```

Now on my edit or submit content I write something like this

```
if(isset($me)) {
  // can edit
} else {
  // logout
}
```

This is working fine, but sometimes the `$me` will return to empty array and user will logout. How to use `$me` correctly.

Let me know..

Comment: @Phill Brown, yes is there `$me = $facebook->api('/me');`

Comment: In my application i didn't use php-sdk but wrote the login functions and session handling my own. Finally I end up writing a class my own to handle this things. I am sorry for not publishing that because its not at all documented.

Comment: @Shameer give me a hint how do you filter the session. Let say I logout from Facebook but in the same time still logged into your app, then I logged back to Facebook using another account and refresh your current app. Is the session using a new one? Let me know.

Comment: It will logout from the app and unset the session when you logout from facebook. When you login using another facebook account it will show that users details. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my test here will working fine

```
if(isset($me) && $facebook->api('/me')) {
  // can edit
} else {
  // logout
}
```